# Cloudbees Tomcat Application IOException

Tags: tomcat, ioexception, cloudbees, sesame, openrdf

I'm using Cloudbees as my Java PaaS, I have created to Tomcat 8 Applications and uploaded two WAR files:

- OpenRDF Workbench
- OpenRDF Sesame

[source: http://www.openrdf.org ]

I uploaded Workbench and after the supposed waiting period, my instance of OpenRDF Workbench was working, I was able to access to web interface.
After, I uploaded Sesame and after the supposed waiting period, I tried to access the URL for sesame, and this appeared:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet openrdf-http-server threw exception

(...)

root cause 
java.io.IOException: Unable to create logging directory /var/genapp/apps/8ec10836/.aduna/openrdf-sesame/logs
    info.aduna.app.logging.base.LogConfigurationBase.setBaseDir(LogConfigurationBase.java:70)
    info.aduna.app.AppConfiguration.init(AppConfiguration.java:155)
    info.aduna.app.AppConfiguration.init(AppConfiguration.java:140)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sesame tries to create a log directory in the given dir, but fails. The most likely cause is a permission issue. Make sure that the user under which tomcat runs has permission to write in that directory, and of course that there is sufficient space - Sesame will want to use the same directory for data persistence.

**edit** If the default location that Sesame uses can not be made writable, you can change the location by setting a system property `info.aduna.platform.appdata.basedir`. See [section 2.5 of the Sesame user docs](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#chapter-datadir-config) for details.

Comment: I know this error/exception being of IO type is related to permissions or access to a filesystem, but Cloudbees being a PaaS I do not have that kind of flexibility when it is related to User perspective, if I have it at least I do not know how to use and configure Cloudbees that way in order to gain that kind of flexibility. And that was the focus of mine question...

Comment: Well I don't know how to do this _in Cloudbees_ but I can give you information about what's going on at Sesame's end. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy this kind of applications on a PaaS, you should be aware that the file system is not persistent, so in case that application uses any kind of configuration file, every time you restart/deploy the application you will lose that information.

The way the file system works on CloudBees is explained [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/File+system+access). As you can see you cannot write files where you want.

> Temporary/ephemeral filesystem access is available to your application. In a java app this is injected as the "java.io.tmpdir" system property - you can store files there as needed. Please note the following:

Comment: I understand, as you and Cloudbees mention it, in order to persist data into files (filesystem) I can only achieve it through "java.io.tmpdir", but being Sesame a third-party (in my perspective) software/application probably I do not have the "capability" (more like "should not") make changes at that level...